# Internet is not working on my HP laptop

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet

I can not connect to net,wired or wireless.I have seen here
[Installed Ubuntu 14.04 - cannot connect to internet with wired or wireless connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488139/installed-ubuntu-14-04-cannot-connect-to-internet-with-wired-or-wireless-conne)
So

```
sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:98200000-98203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:86:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:25:b3:42:05:5c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:30 memory:90100000-90103fff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90120000-9013ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 00:21:00:b2:16:48
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=b43 driverversion=3.19.0-47-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

Then

```
ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:b3:42:05:5c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:369 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:369 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:27937 (27.9 KB)  TX bytes:27937 (27.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:00:b2:16:48  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

And

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:b3:42:05:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:00:b2:16:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

What should I try first?